# Servlet - Applet interaction requires reading responce

Tags: java, servlets, applet

I'm dealing with the following problem.

I have a servelt (with doPost and doGet overrided) and an applet with the following code:

```
        String urlStr="blabla";
        URLConnection conn = StartConnection("http","localhost",8084,urlStr);            
        InputObject obj = GetInputObject();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
```

With this piece of code servlet doesn't do any action (doPost or doGet). But if I add

```
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String result = in.readLine();
        log(result);
```

I get into doPost body. Googling gives nothing. Why do I have to read back responce, even if I don't need it?

added:

```
private URLConnection StartConnection(String protocol,String host,int port, String urlStr){
        URLConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            URL currentPage=getCodeBase();
            URL dataURL=new URL(protocol,host,port,urlStr);
            conn = dataURL.openConnection();            
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
        }
        catch(Exception ee){
                log(ee.getMessage().toString());
        }
        return conn;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't see the source for `StartConnection()` apparently it just returns a unconnected `URLConnection`. Just creating this object doesn't talk to the network at all; this only happens when `connect()` is called. Reading from the input stream implicitly calls `connect()`, so that's why this works for you. You can just call `connect()`, though; you don't actually have to read any data you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a serialized instance of your applet class to your servlet, then you have to make a HTTP call like a browser. You should use POST method and send the serialized bytes as a POST parameter.
The best library for such stuff is [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). Here is a [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html).